# Return DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> from a Stream Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream, provider

I'll appreciate it if someone could help me discover what is going on with this error in my Flutter App.

I think its a problem with the type of data that is returned from the database Stream

In my App, I have to retrieve user information from a Firestore collection of "users" to show in a User Profile screen but I'm getting this error:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following StateError was thrown building UserProfile(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery]):
Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform that does not exist

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  UserProfile file:///Users/JamesMontes/Documents/Flutter-projects/theloudculture/lib/pages/settings/settings_page.dart:30:28
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:76:7)
#1      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.get (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:92:48)
#2      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.[] (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:96:40)
#3      UserProfile.build (package:theloudculture/pages/account/user_profile.dart:31:42)
#4      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4569:28)
...
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform that does not exist
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  UserProfile file:///Users/JamesMontes/Documents/Flutter-projects/theloudculture/lib/pages/settings/settings_page.dart:30:28
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform that does not exist
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  UserProfile file:///Users/JamesMontes/Documents/Flutter-projects/theloudculture/lib/pages/settings/settings_page.dart:30:28
====================================================================================================
```

My files have this code:

database.dart (Where I retrieve user data)

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;

  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  // Get User stream
  Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> get user {
    return usersCollection.doc(uid).snapshots();
  }
}
```

The widget that provides the stream is my Home Widget and have this code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:theloudculture/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:theloudculture/pages/inner_pages.dart';
import 'package:theloudculture/services/database.dart';
import 'package:theloudculture/widgets/widgets.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<CustomUser>(context);

    return StreamProvider<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>.value(
      value: DatabaseService(uid: user != null ? user.uid : null).user,
      child: ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) => NavegacionModel(),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.black,
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            appBar: LoudAppBar(),
            body: Paginas(),
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NavegacionModel with ChangeNotifier {
  int _paginaActual = 0;
  int get paginaActual => this._paginaActual;

  set paginaActual(int valor) {
    this._paginaActual = valor;

    //Notifying widgets
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The settings_page is child of home widget so I'm accessing userData from that widget

```
import 'package:animate_do/animate_do.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:theloudculture/pages/account/user_profile.dart';
import 'package:theloudculture/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:theloudculture/shared/loading.dart';
import 'package:theloudculture/widgets/widgets.dart';

class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userData =
        Provider.of<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(context);

    print(userData);

    return userData == null
        ? Loading()
        : FadeIn(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: UserProfile(userData: userData),
                  ),
                  LargeBtn(
                    btnText: 'Salir',
                    bottomMargin: true,
                    btnAction: () async {
                      await _auth.signOut();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Also, the error mentions UserProfile widget and this is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:theloudculture/pages/account/user_edit_page.dart';
import 'package:theloudculture/pages/account/user_profile_header.dart';
import 'package:theloudculture/shared/loading.dart';
import 'package:theloudculture/widgets/outlined_custom_button.dart';

class UserProfile extends StatelessWidget {
  final userData;

  const UserProfile({
    Key key,
    this.userData,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return userData == null
        ? Loading()
        : Container(
            width: screenSize.width * 0.95,
            height: screenSize.height * 0.7,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                userData == null
                    ? Loading()
                    : UserProfileHeader(
                        userUid: userData['userUid'],
                        userReferrerCode: userData['userReferrerCode'],
                        firstName: userData['firstName'],
                        lastName: userData['lastName'],
                        displayName: userData['displayName'],
                        email: userData['email'],
                        actualProfileImageName: userData['profileImageName'],
                        profileImageUrl: userData['profileImageUrl'],
                      ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Amigos Invitados:'),
                          SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                          Text(userData['invitedFriends'].toString()),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                      OutlinedCustomButton(
                        btnText: 'Editar Perfil',
                        btnAction: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => UserEditPage(),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Aquí van las opciones',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting as an answer as I cannot comment. It is clearly stated in your log that
**Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist**. One of the fields you are fetching does not exist in your database.

Replace

```
    Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> get user {
       return usersCollection.doc(uid).snapshots();
    }
```

With

```
    Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> get user {
       return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('uid', isEqualTo: uid).snapshots();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you make me notice that the user information wasn't being saved to the database and that was the problem returning that error. I was having that error also when a user is created with a profile image, that was because the image upload task was taking some time but the app tried to retrieve the user information that was created after uploading the image. I just change the order of the tasks and the error was solved. Thanks again for your help.